# How to set a variable equal to an object inside a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I'm trying to write a simple word counter using a dictionary.  I am wondering why the following code will not work:

```
while word != None:
      wordObject = Word()
      wordObject.setWord(word)
      if dictionary.has_key(wordObject.getWord():
            setCount = dictionary[wordObject.getWord()]
            setCount.setCount()
```

If I leave this as is it never enters the if statement, if I put a key value in the has key method then it will enter the statement and say that I have invalid syntax on my setCount variable.  I am trying to set that variable to the object stored at the key value in the dictionary I made and then increment the words count with the setCount method. Thanks.

Comment: You have not included your relevant part of your code.. Like your `Word` class.. setCount() method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your whole code but can predict you must be having some method `setCount` in `wordObject` and falsely using a local variable. Changing to `wordObject.setCount()` may help otherwise a simple

```
count = 0
while word != None:
      wordObject = Word()
      wordObject.setWord(word)
      if dictionary.has_key(wordObject.getWord():
            setCount=dictionary[wordObject.getWord()]
            count += 1
```

is enough to store the count.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I finally realized I had a syntactical error on my if statement, but both replies gave me easier ways to implement what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting (Python 2.7+). If you want to count a list of words for example, this is what you'd do:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['stack', 'overflow', 'stack', 'exchange']
counter = Counter(words)

print counter
```

Result:

```
Counter({'stack': 2, 'overflow': 1, 'exchange': 1})
```

A `Counter` is just a dictionary with a few additional convenience methods like `most_common([n])` and it returns zero when trying to get a key that doesn't exist. So if you're on Python < 2.7 you can easily implement your own by subclassing `dict`.